# AWS: How to properly set up mx record for website hosted on AWS S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, email-server, mx-record

I have a static website hosted in an AWS S3 Bucket.  The website works fine.  I've tried adding an MX record using '10 mail.domain.com' in every variation I can think of to write the record but I still can not receive emails. While trying to troubleshoot this issue I've tried looking up my domains IP address but can not find one.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with me hosting my site via the buckets?

Does anyone have any experience setting up MX records for a website hosted on the aws buckets that could offer some advice? IT is not my strong point and I've been stuck on this one for a few days now.  Thanks for taking the time to read!

Domain: ab3d.work

Comment: MX records and websites are unrelated. Where is your email hosted?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I'm not 100% sure where my email is hosted.  I use outlook and was using Azure before switching to AWS.  My email worked fine when I was with Azure.  Is that where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

**Email Host**

Note that S3 is an object store, and has nothing to do with email. You must have an email server or hosted email provider like Google Apps, FastMail, Office 365, Zoho, etc. When you sign up with a provider they will tell you what to set your MX records to so that email for your domain arrives at their servers. Once the email arrives at their servers it's available through their web interface.

I think Zoho has a free tier of email. There are probably thousands of email service providers to choose from. Google and Microsoft are the most well known. I use FastMail, but they've gotten more expensive recently, Google is a better email host and I'd use them if the price is similar.

**MX Records**

If your website domain is example.com you should set the MX record for the domain

```
example.com
```

rather than what you've put above

```
mail.example.com
```

The value 10 is just the priority, it doesn't go in the record itself. DNS providers should allow a field to enter this - at least CloudFlare does.

mail.example.com is a subdomain of your main domain. Sometimes webmail systems are set up on this subdomain, or there may be way to alias it, but I think that's your core problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I made the change to the mx record.  I'll give it some time and follow up to let you know how it goes!

Comment: You can have as many MX records as you like. New MX records, as you've done, should apply immediately. Send an email to the domain, it should arrive. Also note the small edit to my answer around the numbers.

Comment: Thanks again Tim.  Unfortunately no luck so far.  I tried sending myself an email via my gmail account and nothing came through.  while example.com will direct users to my website on the bucket, it also points to some long convoluted url aws assigned to my bucket.  Should I be using that?

Comment: Please edit your question to give us your actual domain name so we can check the MX records directly. Also let us know the IP address of your email server. None of this is secret, MX records are published publicly, and you can always edit your question later if you feel the need to.

Comment: Understood, its updated! I asked the same question on reddit and one of the responces was that the aws s3 buckets do not host emails servers and that I need to look in the aws ses tool.

Comment: Ah. Sorry that's such a basic thing I didn't think to even ask. Yes, you need to have an email server or hosted email service to point your MX records at. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I see on my Outlook web app it has as list of 'incorrect DNS records'.  I've copied a few to my AWS rout53.  Rout53 excepts some, others not.  For example route 53 won't take my outlook mx record without adding the '10', or any of the cname values.  I'm still working though it but it nice to see on the outlook UI what exactly the issues are.

Comment: I think it's time you hire someone to help, as there's something fundamental you're doing wrong, but I'm not sure what. You don't have any MX servers defined for the domain you listed above. [See here](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3aab3d.work&run=toolpage#). Could just be you haven't pointed at the correct name servers from your domain registrar, but we can't really teach you DNS.

Comment: I'm start to accept I may to hire someone.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.  I'll post the issue once it (eventually) get figured out.

Comment: It's not particularly complex, but if you don't have the technical background it may seem that way. I've implemented email systems for dozens of customers. Key might be to ensure your domain registrar is pointing at your DNS provider (route53), and then R53 is publishing the DNS records properly.

Comment: So.... I think I have all my dns records finally set up correctly in route53.  My website loads fine(I broke it earlier) and in the outlook domain settings is says its status is 'healthy' after fixing the errors.  I'm sill unable to to receive emails.  Will it take time for that to update?

Comment: Should be very quick. Go to the link a few comments above and choose "find problems". Nothing obvious jumps out to me, those errors look minor. Not sure what's wrong now.